# Customizing Devise sign_in authentication with bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I am using Devise for authentication, but I want to use my own form input.

I have checked that Devise's sign_in works. I was able to login with this on `localhost:3000/users/sign_in` :

```
<h2>Log in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I created on index page this form, but I could not get it to work (I was not able to login with the code below):

```
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="user_email" placeholder="email?">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword2">/</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_password" placeholder="password?">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
      </form>
```

I read [formhelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) on rubyonrails.org website and [bootstrap's css page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) but it still did not clear up how to use bootstrap's form.

Here are some of the things I don't understand:

The following code `<input type="email" class="form-control" id="user_email" placeholder="email?">`, what should I put for `type=` and `id=`? How can I tell bootstrap's form to submit a post request for my session? I can somewhat read and interpret Devise' form: `<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>` by looking at it: resource is :user, the url is being sent to user's session. I could not find information online about bootstrap's form.  How can I integrate my own custom form using bootstrap with Devise' session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has not really something to do with Bootstrap at first. I would try to get the form working, before you add bootstrap.

The from could be created like this:

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => session_path(:user)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
  <%= f.label :remember_me %>
  <%= f.submit 'Sign in' %>
  <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(:user) %>
<% end %>
```

Now you add some bootstrap flavor to this form:

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => session_path(:user)) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: 'example@example.com' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
    <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
    <%= f.label :remember_me %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit 'Sign in', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <%# link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(:user) %>
<% end %>
```

Most of the information I is from [this page of the devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app).

Comment: Thank you so much! In addition to your comment, I also learned about Devise wiki - something I never knew existed before! https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki